# Perl grep into hash with arrays as values

Tags: arrays, perl

I am building a small web service which has the following routes

```
my %routes = (
  'News' => ['^news', '^news\/?(.*)?', '^news\/(\d+)\/(edit|delete|update)'],
  'User' => ['^users', '^users\/?(.*)?', '^users\/(\d+)\/(edit|delete|update)'],
);
```

each key in the %routes is a module, and the corresponding array holds the possible requests that are supported by the module.

So in case the request is "news/3/edit" the news module should be found and returned.

What I would like to do, is to grep the correct key, if it's corresponding array values matches the incoming request.

Comment: You don't seem to have included a question in your question, but you might find [Router::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Router::Simple) helpful for this.

Comment: Thanks, nice module, Ill look into that

Comment: There is no need to escape the slashes in your regex patterns. It is necessary only to distinguish them from the default delimiter in literal regexes. You also seem to be a little liberal with your non-greedy `?` modifiers. Anything that matches, for example, `^news\/?(.*)?` will have already been matched by just `^news`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a framework that enables you to create routes, it will be much simpler in the long run. In answer to your general question though, you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use List::Util qw(any);

my %routes = (
  'News' => ['^news', '^news\/?(.*)?', '^news\/(\d+)\/(edit|delete|update)'],
  'User' => ['^users', '^users\/?(.*)?', '^users\/(\d+)\/(edit|delete|update)'],
);

sub match { 
   my ($string_to_match) = @_;

   foreach my $module ( keys %routes ) {
      return $module if any { $string_to_match =~ m/$_/ } @{$routes{$module}}
   }

   return;
}
```

Then you can say something like:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use feature qw(say);
use MatchRoutes; # or whatever your package is called

say MatchRoutes->new->match('news/3/edit');
```

Comment: There is no need to escape the slashes in your regex patterns. It is necessary only to distinguish them from the default delimiter in literal regexes. You also seem to be a little liberal with your non-greedy `?` modifiers. Anything that matches, for example, `^news\/?(.*)?` will have been matched already by just `^news`.

Comment: You are correct of course, but I just took the regular expressions from the question without spending much (read any) time validating them.

Comment: Yes, of course that's fine. My intention was to comment on the OP's code, and I shall duplicate it there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the regex's are just to give you an idea of the purpose of the solution I was looking for